# entrepreneur vs. businessperson

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

Is an entrepreneur necessarily a businessperson? My understanding is that an entrepreneur is necessarily a businessperson, but not the other way around.

If that's the case, is the following sentence anomalous?

> John is not a businessperson but an entrepreneur.

Could it have a sensible interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

Usually an entrepreneur is also a businessman or businesswoman. But suppose John is an inventor. He has a new idea, and creates and patents a new product based on that idea. He sets up a business to exploit that idea, but takes into partnership or hires a business expert to run his new company. Then one might say:

> John is not a businessperson but an entrepreneur.

It is a somewhat unusual but possible situation.

Comment: Do you mean if an entrepreneur hires someone to run his business, then he is not a businessperson?

Comment: @Apollyon well s/he **might** not b e, depending on his or her role in the company. But it would be unusual.

Answer (score 1):

The “entrepreneur” is someone who bears risk by starting something new. The newness may not lie in a fundamentally new idea. It may lie only in applying something old in a new place or with minor variations on an established template, But the basic idea is incurring financial risk through some form of innovation.

A business person is responsible for managing a business, perhaps alone (as in a sole proprietorship) or perhaps jointly (as in a partnership).

Thus, it is not necessarily true that an entrepreneur is a business person: a shipowner who provided a ship and a cargo to a captain and supercargo was an entrepreneur, but the supercargo was the business person.

Most entrepreneurs are business persons, but most business persons are not entrepreneurs,

Comment: In your shipowner example, could he still be considered to be managing his business, but by proxy? If so, he satisfies the definition of businessperson indirectly.

Comment: @Apollyon That clearly is one way to look at it. I may be too influenced by usage among economists, going back to at least Adam Smith. Many economists view as important the distinction between the risk bearing entrepreneur and the non-risk bearing manager. Those same economists recognize that one individual can combine multiple roles, but tend to analyze in terms of what Weber called ideal types. And lawyers distinguish between principal and agent.  I may be too influenced by usage in fields that I am familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Let's discuss the differences between businessperson and entrepreneur:
A *businessperson* is anyone who manages, sets up, or runs a **business of any kind**. An *entrepreneur* is a person who sets up a business based on a **new idea** of some sort.

This seems to be in line with your understanding: All entrepreneurs are businesspeople, but not all businesspeople are entrepreneurs.

Given that, your sentence **is somewhat anomalous**. If John has founded a business on a new idea, it goes without saying that he's founded a business. This makes him a businessman.

If one were to look for any way in which the sentence might be sensibly interpreted, you could perhaps argue that if John *founded* a business but does not *actively operate* one, the sentence applies. However this is a stretch, and a particularly pedantic understanding of the words which would probably not be used.

Comment: But the OP's sentence is exactly the reverse of yours, so your generally correct argument does not apply.

Comment: oops; i have misread OP's sentence. editing now.